# Add sound filters and connect sound pins

Tags: c#, audio, directshow, avi, directshow.net

### Context

WPF UI with a user control that instanciate multiple COMS and use filters with directshow.net

### Problem

The audio pins' names change depending on which video is playing. ( both are .avi files )
As you can see in the screenshots, the sound pins are not the same. (one is 'Stream 01', while the other one is '01 Microsoft wave form ..... ')

In my code, I use ConnectDirect and the method GetPin. To use GetPin, you need to give a pin name.

### Graphs

Graph generated with exactly the same code, only change the video files.

[image: Graph generated with exactly the same code, only change the video files.]

### Question

How do I connect the filters when the pins name change depending on which .avi file is running ? btw one avi file is 'home made' while the other is a microsoft avi sample file (12 seconds blue clock)

### Relevant code

```
//sound filter linker
IBaseFilter pACMWrapper = (IBaseFilter)new ACMWrapper();
hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter(pACMWrapper, "ACM wrapper");


//add le default direct sound device

IBaseFilter pDefaultDirectSoundDevice = null;

try
{
    pDefaultDirectSoundDevice = (IBaseFilter)new DSoundRender();
    hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter(pDefaultDirectSoundDevice, "Default DirectSound Device");


    IBaseFilter aviSplitter;
    //find the avi splitter automatically added when I connect samp grabber to source filter.
    m_FilterGraph.FindFilterByName("AVI Splitter", out aviSplitter);

    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(""); // graph screenshot is from here.

    hr = m_FilterGraph.Connect(GetPin(aviSplitter, "Stream 01"), GetPin(pACMWrapper, "Input"));
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

    //connect audio filters 
    hr = m_FilterGraph.ConnectDirect(GetPin(pACMWrapper, "Output"), GetPin(pDefaultDirectSoundDevice, "Audio Input pin (rendered)"), null);
    DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    pDefaultDirectSoundDevice = null;
    //log error, play video without sound
    //throw;
}
```

### GetPin code

```
    private IPin GetPin(IBaseFilter destinationFilter, string pinName)
    {
        IEnumPins pinEnum;
        int hr = destinationFilter.EnumPins(out pinEnum);
        DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);

        IPin[] pins = new IPin[1];

        IntPtr fetched = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(4);

        while (pinEnum.Next(1, pins, fetched) == 0)
        {
            PinInfo pInfo;
            pins[0].QueryPinInfo(out pInfo);

            bool found = (pInfo.name == pinName);
            DsUtils.FreePinInfo(pInfo);
            if (found)
                return pins[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to choose an output pin using a hardcoded name. Instead, and it is a more reliable way in fact, you need to enumerate pins - as your `GetPin` function already does - then enumerating media types on the given pin. It is OK to look just at the first media type (if any). If its major type is `MEDIATYPE_Audio` then it's your pin to take, regardless of its effective name.

Comment: Dude. You are the master and the oracle of that tower of babel that is Directshow. You got my respect from Saguenay, QC, Canada.